# Multiple values in one field Yii2

Tags: yii2

How to display multpiple values in one field.. I Use Select2 Widget. If i use $courses_model[0] it display only one value

Controller

```
public function actionUpdateteachers($id)
{
    $courses_model = ReferenceTeachersCourses::find()->where(['reference_teachers_id' => $id])->all();
    .....
 }
```

View

```
...
<?= $form->field($courses_model[0], 'reference_course_type_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' =>ArrayHelper::map($courses,'id','name'),
    'options' => ['multiple' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],
]);
...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This widgets works fine - but your $courses_model[0]->reference_course_type_id must have an array of ids as a value if you want to see multiple values selected.